# Problem - cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

A circular membrane in space is about the region $x^2 + y^2 \leqslant a^2$. The maximum $z$ component is $b$. Suppose that $(x, y, z)$ is a point on the membrane. Show that the corresponding point in cylindrical coordinates $(r, \theta, z)$ satisfies the conditions $ 0 \leqslant r \leqslant a, \space 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi, \mid z \mid \leqslant b$.

I understand everything but I just can't prove it...

Answer (score 0):

The membrane is the following set
$$
M=\{(x,y,z)\;|\; x^2+y^2 \le a^2, -b \le z \le b \}
$$
In cylindrical coordinates, this yields
$$
M=\{(r,\theta,z)\;|\; 0 \le r \le a, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, -b \le z \le b \}
$$
So if a point belongs to $M$, the result follows.